# Java: System.out.println и System.err.println путаются в выводе

Tags: java, потоки-данных

Есть задача: с помощью команд System.out.println и System.err.println вывести текст в красной рамке. Типа вот так:

```
*******
*текст*
*******
```

Но при выводе в IDEA всё время вылетает то текст до рамки, то после, то иначе, но не по заданию. В Eclipse видел, что работает.
Понимаю, что в потоках проблема, а решить не получается.

```
System.err.print("*******\n");
System.err.print("|");
System.out.print("text");
System.err.print("|");
System.err.print("*******\n");
```

Comment: Не надо исрользовать stderr для краной подсветки. Он не буферизируется и может выскочить где угодно.

Comment: Добавлю: кроме того, красный цвет работает только в IDE. В реальной консоли текст останется точно таким же.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так (очищать буфер после каждого вывода):

```
print(System.err, "*******\n");
print(System.err,"|");
print(System.out,"text");
print(System.err,"|");
print(System.err,"*******\n");

private void print(PrintStream ps, String output)  {
    ps.print(output);
    ps.flush();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что `System.out.print` буферизирует данные для вывода, в отличие от `System.err.print`.

Что это значит ?

Например, вы печатаете используя `System.out.println`. Затем производите какие-то операции, затем опять печатаете. `System.out.println` произведет печать всех элементов сразу, а не по очередно.

`System.err.print` мгновенно выводит элементы на печать, не буферизируя данные.

Comment: Вот здесь бы кинуть ссылку на документацию или какую-то нормальную ссылку. Я вот прямо не уверен в том, что `System.err` практикует небуферизованный вывод, хотя логикак конечно же есть в этом

Answer (score 0):

Решили задачу так:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        System.err.print("**********\n|  ");
        System.err.flush();
        Thread.sleep(50);
        System.out.print("text");
        System.out.flush();
        Thread.sleep(50);
        System.err.print("  |\n**********");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```